Stacking transparent solar panels would increase the efficiency of the system?
From what I could understand, there are multi-junction solar panels that are transparent in certain wavelengths and opaque in others, but I'm not referring to them.
I'm referring to the idea of stacking the same type of transparent or semi-transparent solar cells one after another.
Since they are transparent/semi-transparent, doesn't that mean that only a fraction of the light wavelength was converted into electricity and the rest of its energy just passed through them? Thus allowing subsequent transparent solar panels to react to that other portion of light until it fully loses its energy?
If it was that simple, someone would’ve already made it, but I want to understand why it doesn’t work.

What you describe is, in fact, an opaque solar panel, which was invented before transparent ones. I have a few on top of my house.
